# Freeware Query Builder

Tags: sql, database

I'm looking for some freeware Query Builder.

Query Builder in Aqua Data Studio allows you to visually build queries:

1. select the column you want returned
2. generates joins for you(you just select by which columns you want to join it)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! I thought there were many DB tools that fit your description, but when I checked a commonly-sourced Wikipedia article (see comment below), I found that most free/open source DB management software does not have a visual query builder feature! (I build my queries from scratch, so this is not a feature I particularly need.)

The freeware version of [Toad for Data Analysts](http://www.toadworld.com/DOWNLOADS/Freeware/ToadforDataAnalystsFreeware/tabid/559/Default.aspx) is a good bet. You can download and use it for 120 days. After that time, you need to reinstall on your PC. You might need to check to see if you will get write-access to non-Oracle databases, but I do know you can at least get read access to most non-Oracle DBs.

You might also like [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/featurelist-094691.html), which has a more robust community of users than that of the *Freeware* Toad for Data Analysts. That will only give you read-only access to certain non-Oracle databases.

Comment: The Wikipedia article I referenced in the first paragraph above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools